# Prove that there is $x \in [0,1]$ such that $|f''(x)| > 4$

Tags: calculus

> Assume $f$ has a continuous second derivative with $f(0) = f'(0) = f'(1) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Prove that there is $x \in [0,1]$ such that $|f''(x)| > 4$.

We must also have that $f'$ is continuous by differentiability. Therefore, by Rolles theorem there exists a $c$ in $[0,1]$ such that $f''(c) = 0$. I am not sure how to use the fact that $f(1) = 1$ to show that $|f''(x)| > 4$.

Comment: How about using Taylor series expansion?

Comment: @Larara What if $f$ doesn't have a convergent Taylor series expansion?

Comment: The average slope of $f(x)$ over the interval must be $1$, and therefore there must be a $c_1$ such that $f'(c_1)\ge 1$; you can probably prove that such a point must occur at a point $c_2$ where $f''(c_2)=0$, and you can again apply logic, this time to say that the average slope of $f'(x)$ must be greater than $4$ since the interval is at most $\frac14$ of the length of the original...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll  prove strict inequality by contradiction.

Set $g=f'$. By hypothesis, $g$ is $C^1$  on $[0,1]$, $\;g(0)=g(1)=0$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^1g(x)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=1$.

Suppose $\lvert g'(x)\rvert\le 4$. This means

- $g'\le 4$, which implies $g(x)\le 4x$ on $\bigl[0,\frac12\bigr]$ so that
  $$\int_0^{1/2}\!\!g(x)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x\le4\int_0^{1/2}x\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=\frac12.$$ Furthermore, we have equality if and only if $g(x)=4x$ on  $\bigl[0,\frac12\bigr]$.
- $g'\ge -4$, which implies $g(x)\le 4(1-x)$ on $\bigl[\frac12,1\bigr]$ so that $$\int_{1/2}^1g(x)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x\le4\int_{1/2}^1(1-x)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=\frac12,$$ and we have equality if and only if $ g(x)=4((1-x) $ on $\bigl[\frac12,1\bigr]$.

Now, as $\displaystyle \int_0^1g(x)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=1$, we do have equality in both cases. Thus $g$ is defined by
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}4x &\text{if}\enspace x\in\bigl[0,\frac12\bigr],\\
4(1-x)&\text{if}\enspace x\in\bigl[\frac12,1\bigr].
\end{cases}$$
This contradicts derivability of $g$ at $x=\frac12$.

Comment: Not at all: the problem stipulates  $f$ is $C^2$, hence $f'$ is $C^1$.

Comment: Yes because at $x=\frac12$, $g$ has a left derivative equal to $4$ and a right derivative equal to $-4$. This contradicts being differentiable on $[0,1]$.

Comment: But that might mean that $g' < -4$? Also I don't see how taking the equality case in both cases can make a contradiction.

Comment: The curve is not smooth at $x=\frac12$ since it has only (different) one sided derivatives. The hypotheses say it does have a (two-sided) derivative. That is contradiction: it both has and has not a derivative at a point.

Comment: How do you know in the first case equality is achieved if and only if $g(x) = 4x$?

Comment: This means $\int_0^{1/2}\bigl(g(x)-4x\bigr)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=0$, and $g(x)-4x$ is continuous, $\ge 0$. This implies $g(x)-4x=0$.

Comment: I think you mean that since $g(x) - 4x \leq 0$, we must have $g(x) = 4x.$

Comment: Oh! Yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: One more thing: how do you know $g(x) \leq 4x$ on $[0,1/2]$ and not $[0,1]$?

Comment: I didn't say it was not true on $[0,1]$. I use the inequality on the interval which is useful in the context.

Comment: Nice solution! This does assume, though, that such a function exists right? Otherwise our proof may be invalid.

Comment: You can easily sketch one  by hand, hence it must exist (take a suitable Bézier curve). It's a classical, not-so-easy exercise.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(\frac{1}{2}) = f(0) + f'(0)(\frac{1}{2}) + \frac{f''(\theta_1)}{2}(\frac{1}{2})^2 = f''(\theta_1)\frac{1}{8}$$
$$f(\frac{1}{2}) = f(1) - f'(1)(\frac{1}{2}) + \frac{f''(\theta_2)}{2}(\frac{1}{2})^2 = 1 + f''(\theta_2)\frac{1}{8}$$
Here, $0\le \theta_1 \le 1/2$, and $1/2 \le \theta_2 \le 1$
Combining both, we have
$$ 1 = f''(\theta_1)\frac{1}{8} - f''(\theta_2)\frac{1}{8}$$
Take absolute value,
$$ 1 \le max \{|f''(\theta_1)|, |f''(\theta_2)|\} \frac{1}{4}$$

So c is one of $\theta_1, \theta_2$.

Let 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x^2\, \text{ for } 0 \le x \le 1/2\\ -2(x-1)^2 +1\, \text{ for } 1/2 < x \le 1 \end{cases}$$

$$f''(x) = 4$$, so the equality holds for this f.

Comment: Two of your $f''(\theta_1)$ should be  $f''(\theta_2)$.

Comment: That only gives an $x$ with $|f''(x)|\ge 4$. The problem asks for strict inequality.

Comment: We don't want to show equality. We want to show greater than or equal to.

Comment: corrected typos, and give an example that the equality holds.

Comment: Are you using the Lagrange remainder?

Comment: @Puzzled417,  the inequality has been proved. Just and a particular example to clarify the confusion to give an example when the equality actually holds.

Comment: @runaround Do you see that there is a difference between $>$ and $\geq$?

Comment: Yes, I do see. But there is function that holds the equalty. So the question is incorrect to require <.

Comment: @runaround Are you using the Lagrange remainder?

Comment: Am I missing something? It seems in your example that $f''(x)=4$ for $0<x<1/2$ and $f''(x)=-4$ for $1/2<x<1$, so it doesn't meet the hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\eqalign{
1&=f(1)-f(0)=\int_0^1 f'(x)\,dx\cr
&=\int_0^{1/2}f'(x)\,dx+\int_{1/2}^1 f'(x)\,dx\cr
&=\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^xf''(t)\,dt\,dx-\int_{1/2}^1 \int_x^1f''(t)\,dt\,dx\cr
&=\int_0^{1/2}(1/2-t)f''(t)\,dt-\int_{1/2}^1 (t-1/2)f''(t)\,dt.\cr
}
$$
Consequently, if $|f''(t)|\le 4$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, then by the above and the triangle inequality,
$$
\eqalign{
1&\le 4
\int_0^{1/2}(1/2-t)\,dt+4\int_{1/2}^1(t-1/2)\,dt\cr
&=-2(1/2-t)^2\Big|_0^{1/2}+2(t-1/2)^2\Big|_{1/2}^1\cr
&=1/2+1/2=1.\cr
}
$$
It follows that
$$
\int_0^{1/2}(1/2-t)|f''(t)|\,dt=\int_{1/2}^1 (t-1/2)|f''(t)|\,dt=1/2,
$$
which togetther with the hypothesis $|f''(t)|\le 4$ for all $t$ implies that $|f''(t)|=4$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. As $f''$ is continuous, we must have either $f''(t)=4$ for all $t$ or $f''(t)=-4$ for all $t$. In the first case $f(x)=2x^2$ in violation of $f(1)=1$. Likewise  the second alternative leads to a contradiction.